# Unable to read bigquery table with JSON/RECORD column type into spark dataframe. ( java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected type: JSON)

Tags: json, pyspark, google-bigquery, apache-spark-sql, spark-bigquery-connector

we are trying to read a table from Bigquery to spark dataframe.

Strucute of the table is
[image: simple_table]

Following pyspark code is used for reading the data.

```py
    from google.oauth2 import service_account
    from google.cloud import bigquery
    import json
    import base64 as bs
    from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StructType, StringType, IntegerType, DoubleType, DecimalType
    
    schema = "schema_name"
    project_id = "project_id"
    
    table_name = "simple"
    # table_name = "jsonres"
    schema_table_name = str(project_id) + "." + str(schema) + "." + str(table_name)
    credentials_dict = {"Insert_actual_credentials": "here"}

    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(credentials_dict)
    client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials, project=project_id)
    
    query = "SELECT * FROM `{}`;".format(schema_table_name)
    # print(query)
    query_job = client.query(query)
    query_job.result()
    
    s = json.dumps(credentials_dict)
    res = bs.b64encode(s.encode('utf-8'))
    ans = res.decode("utf-8")
    
    try:
        df = spark.read.format('bigquery') \
            .option("credentials", ans) \
            .option("parentProject", project_id) \
            .option("project", project_id) \
            .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED") \
            .option('dataset', query_job.destination.dataset_id) \
            .load(query_job.destination.table_id)
        df.printSchema()
        print(df)
        df.show()
    except Exception as exp:
        print(exp)
```

For simple tables, we are able to read table as dataframe successfully.

But when we have json column in the big query table as given below, we are getting error.
[image: json_col_table]

We are getting the following error.

> An error occurred while calling o1138.load. :
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected type: JSON    at
> com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.SchemaConverters.getStandardDataType(SchemaConverters.java:355)
> at
> com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.SchemaConverters.lambda$getDataType$3(SchemaConverters.java:303)

We also tried by providing schema while reading the data.

```py
structureSchema = StructType([ \
        StructField('x', StructType([
             StructField('name', StringType(), True)
             ])),
    StructField("y", DecimalType(), True) \
  ])
print(structureSchema)

try:
    df = spark.read.format('bigquery') \
        .option("credentials", ans) \
        .option("parentProject", project_id) \
        .option("project", project_id) \
        .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED") \
        .option('dataset', query_job.destination.dataset_id) \
        .schema(structureSchema) \
        .load(query_job.destination.table_id)
    df.printSchema()
    print(df)
    df.show()
except Exception as exp:
    print(exp)
```

Still we faced the same error 'java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected type: JSON'.

How to read bigquery table with json type into spark dataframe?

Update 1:
There is an open issue in github regarding this.

[While reading a bigquery table, having a JSON type field from Apache Spark throws exception.](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector/issues/804)

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a corresponding Github issue for this in bigquery connector repository.

[While reading a bigquery table, having a JSON type field from Apache Spark throws exception.  · Issue #804 · GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector/issues/804)

**They are saying issue is fixed in 0.28.0 and above versions.**

Commit containing their fix: json related changes

[#804 · abhijeet-lele/spark-bigquery-connector@0c7de63](https://github.com/abhijeet-lele/spark-bigquery-connector/commit/0c7de63b7326991d44966642f8cac4de8cd4651f)

[image: commit_Screenshot]

Maven Repository: [com.google.cloud.spark » spark-bigquery](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud.spark/spark-bigquery)
[image: maven_ss]

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below and check if it works for you, basically, you will keep the JSON column as a string, and then you can use the spark function to get the JSON content

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

structureSchema = StructType([
    StructField('x', StringType()),
    StructField("y", DecimalType())
  ])

df = (spark.read.format('bigquery')
        .option("credentials", ans)
        .option("parentProject", project_id)
        .option("project", project_id)
        .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
        .option('dataset', query_job.destination.dataset_id)
        .schema(structureSchema)
        .load(query_job.destination.table_id)
     )

df = df.withColumn("jsonColumnName", f.get_json_object(f.col("x"), "$.name"))
```

Comment: StructType(List(StructField(x,StringType,true),StructField(y,StringType,true)))
An error occurred while calling o2036.load.
: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected type: JSON
 at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.SchemaConverters.getStandardDataType(SchemaConverters.java:355)
 at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.SchemaConverters.lambda$getDataType$3(SchemaConverters.java:303)

Even with string type, we are facing error